# When running "php bin/console list", Symfony prints the code for several classes inside the "src/Admin"-directory

Tags: php, symfony

I've taken over a code base of a Symfony 4.4-project, with a couple of extra bundles installed (Sonata being the biggest one). When I write: `php bin/console list`, then it prints the source code for several of the classes in the `src/Admin`-directory. And I can't figure out why.

I've searched the code for `print`, `var_dump` and `dump`, but can't figure out where this is.

I'm not familiar enough with Symfony, to go through the code 'from the top', adding my own dump-statements, narrowing it down, where this code is coming from.

Had this been Laravel, then I would have started in the routes, then moved on to maybe the kernel or middleware, then to the controlles - and in the end the views.

Does anyone have a good suggestion on which files to add dump-statements to, to see where this code is coming from?
... Or if anyone else has a good idea on how to find this code, then I'm all ears.

Is it maybe an entire namespace that is printed? And can one even do that?! Hmm...

---

This is what it looks like:

[image: PHP bin/console]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get this behavior if the code you've inherited uses short open tags `<?` but your personal dev environment's PHP installation has them disabled. Run `php --ini` to find where your ini file is and then edit that to change from this:

```
short_open_tag = Off
```

To this:

```
short_open_tag = On
```

Alternatively, you could edit all the source files and change the short open tags `<?` to long open tags `<?php`.